# How to run Lua script from within VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, scripting, vscode-extensions

Have been using `Notepad++` for awhile now, and adding scripts via `Lua` extensions. Now, I would like to get my feet wet using `VS Code` and was wondering what sort of extensibility I could leverage in that environment? Possible to run the same `Lua` scripts, for instance? Or are there other avenues I should consider? Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 7):

Please install the vs-code extensions "LuaDebug" and "extensionPath" provided by actboy168.

Add a file named `.vscode/launch.json` with the content:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lua",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.lua"
        }
    ]
}
```

if your source to be executed is `src/main.lua`.

Then hit `F5` or "Run"->"Start Debugging", select the lauch configuration and happy debugging.

An example is also shipped by the author of the plug-in (actboy128), which can be found here: https://github.com/actboy168/luamake

Please do not try to build it, simply load it in VS Code and debug it!

Comment: There is no need to install any interpreter? The plugin contains it?

Comment: You just need to install  the extension "LuaDebug" ( actboy168 ) ; it includes lua 5.4.
 
Then add the file `.vscode/launch.json` and start debugging (e.g. press `<F5>`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following settings to run the interpreter from VSCode using the menu option "Terminal|Run Build Task":

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run Lua",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "lua54",
            "args": ["${file}"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The file contains this settings must be named as "tasks.json". I suggest you to read the VSCode in order to learn how to create it properly.

NOTE: in the command property, where you read "lua54", you must write the name of the lua interpreter executable without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to configure a [task file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) to run lua from VS code and install lua on your pc if it's isn't done yet.

In order to debug lua you would have to install the extension [lua debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=actboy168.lua-debug) which will add a ton of useful feature to help you debug lua such as breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to touch on several topics:

1. How to run a Lua script from VS Code: other answers here have already addressed it.
2. How to extend VS Code: pull up the extension view in VS Code, find an extension you like, and click install.  More info here:
   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace
3. How to author VS Code extensions: they are written in TypeScript or JavaScript rather than Lua.  More info here:
   https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Answer (score 0):

you can type the following in cmd and it will run the command. Instead of installing extensions.

```
"C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe" "D:\game"
```

--> this is the path where your main.lua file is