# Debugging Lua script with torch in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, torch

I want to debug the repository https://github.com/lifrordi/DeepStack-Leduc with VSCode.

I cloned the repo, downloaded Lua and torch and I can run the program from the terminal without any issues, e.g.:

```
th DataGeneration/main_data_generation.lua
```

For debugging main_data_generation.lua with VSCode, I added the "Lua Debug" and "extensionPath" extensions as suggested here: [How to run Lua script from within VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193174/how-to-run-lua-script-from-within-vs-code).

Everything works fine, until I come across the torch-require statement:

```
local torch = require 'torch'
```

The debugger gives me the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: module 'torch' not found:
no field package.preload['torch']
no file 'somePath/torch.lua'
no file 'somePath/torch.lua'
no file 'somePath/torch.so'
no file 'somePath/torch.so'
```

When I downloaded torch from https://github.com/torch/distro.git, it created a folder named torch, but there are no such files as torch.lua or torch.so.

I tried to put the torch directory in the source directory (which corresponds to "somePath" in the above error) but that didn't help.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this are highly appreciated!